# mysql linked table + join + count

Tags: mysql, optimization, count

I've got a query that i'd like to optimize. I'm certain that this query can be improved.

The result of the query should return the number of products that have the filter_id 22 and 2 and have display 'yes'.

```
SELECT COUNT(product_id) AS Total
FROM kkx_filters_products
    LEFT JOIN kkx_products ON product_id = kkx_products.id
WHERE filter_id IN (2,22)
  AND kkx_products.display = 'yes'
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING count(product_id) = 2
```

The above query returns 10230 records each with the field Total and value 2.
I'd like one result with the field Total and value 10230.

I've included the structure of the tables being used in the query.

EXPLAIN kkx_filters;

```
Field            Type                 Null  Key     Default        Extra
id               int(11) unsigned     NO    PRI     NULL           auto_increment
name             varchar(50)          NO
```

EXPLAIN kkx_filters_products;

```
Field            Type                 Null  Key   Default          Extra
filter_id        int(11)              NO    PRI   0    
product_id       int(11)              NO    PRI   0
```

EXPLAIN kkx_products;

```
Field            Type                 Null  Key   Default          Extra
id               int(11)              NO    PRI   NULL             auto_increment
title            varchar(255)         NO            
display          enum('yes','no')     NO          yes
```

Comment: `... the count as rows... one result with the result`... huh?

Comment: *"should return the number of products that have the filter_id 22 **and** 2"* But the `HAVING count( product_id ) = 1` means either 22 **or** 2. WHich one is it?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I have formulated my question more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your query with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  ( yourquery ) AS tmp
```

but it won't be very efficient. Instead, join the products table to the filter table, twice:

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
      kkx_products AS p 
  JOIN  
      kkx_filters_products AS f1 
    ON  f1.product_id = p.id
    AND f1.filter_id = 2
  JOIN  
      kkx_filters_products AS f2 
    ON  f2.product_id = p.id
    AND f2.filter_id = 22
WHERE 
      p.display = 'yes'
```